# If things miss each other from one observer's perspective, do they miss in all perspectives?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

I have this thought experiment and I'm not quite sure if it works out.

So there is a UFO. It is travelling close to the speed of light. There is also a sniper on the ground on Earth. Relative to the sniper, the UFO contracts by $10\ \mathrm{m}$. The sniper shoots and from his perspective he misses by $2\ \mathrm{m}$. Through my understanding, the bullet should hit the UFO because its rest length is actually 10m longer. 
Can you guys please explain to me whether I am correct or incorrect?

Comment: No one is going to be able to show you an exact demonstration that observers in both frames agree on the outcome when you haven't specified the conditions of the question. That said, there can't be two opinions on "hit or miss" as this is a thing that happens (or doesn't happen) at a single space-time event. And frankly *no one* reasons well in terms of length contraction; draw a space-time diagram of the event.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I had a completely wrong thought experiment.